# “Access Denied” trying to execute a command using alternate credentials as user SYSTEM

Tags: powershell, system, credentials

I have a script that runs as SYSTEM, if i try to `start-process notepad.exe` it's working fine. if i add `-credentials $cred` it shows Access Denied. The credentials i pass over has local admin access, so why is there Access Denied? with procmon on powershell.exe i can not identify any access denied operation, i can see that powershell access notepad.exe with success result.

any ideas?

in one forum-post I read that it's not possible to execute a command with -credentials as SYSTEM. is that so?
if so, is there any workaround?

to my background, i use a software distribution where any installation runs as SYSTEM, from there i want to execute a powershell script as different user.

Comment: i also tried it with psexec... same problem. i found this: PsExec uses CreateProcessWithLogonW; note that the documentation for the function states: You cannot call CreateProcessWithLogonW from a process that is running under the LocalSystem account, because the function uses the logon SID in the caller token, and the token for the LocalSystem account does not contain this SID. As an alternative, use the CreateProcessAsUser and LogonUser functions. i guess it's the same behavior in powershell. how can i use "CreateProcessAsUser" in pwoershell?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force 
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('domain\user', $secpasswd) 
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Process powershell c:\temp\mmc.ps1 -verb runas -wait} -ComputerName localhost -Credential $mycreds -Verbose
```

its not exactly what i want because here you need to enable psremoting first. but its like a workaround.

any idea how this is possible without invoke-command would be appreciated